# Override property in application.groovy with external config in grails 3

Tags: grails, spring-boot, grails-3.0

There is no `grails.config.locations` property in grails 3 anymore, now Grails 3 uses Spring's property source concept instead, but how can I achieve the same behavior in grails 3 as it was in previous versions? Suppose I want to override some property `property.to.be.overridden` in application.grovy file with my external configuration file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of `grails.config.locations` is `spring.config.location`

> http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Here is an example specifying configuration locations while launching a jar from the command line(These same arguments can be used inside of your ide)

```
 java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

Also since you mention wanting to override properties it's useful to learn the way Spring Boot handles profile specific property files(Multiple profiles may also be specified)

> http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Comment: As explained by Graeme here  : http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-3-External-config-td4658823.html

You can use properties.

`-Dcom.foo="test"`
 overrides  **com.foo** from application.yaml.
And you can add an external groovy file if you want, see the post.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this a slightly different way, so I could load an external YAML file.

**Application.groovy**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp

import grails.boot.GrailsApp
import grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean
import org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application)
    }

    @Override
    void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        String configPath = System.properties["myapp.config.location"]
        if (configPath) {
            Resource resourceConfig = new FileSystemResource(configPath);
            YamlPropertiesFactoryBean propertyFactoryBean = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
            propertyFactoryBean.setResources(resourceConfig);
            propertyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
            Properties properties = propertyFactoryBean.getObject();
            environment.propertySources.addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("myapp.config.location", properties))
        }
    }
}
```

Then I specify the YAML file when I run it

**command line**

```
java -jar -Dmyapp.config.location=/etc/myapp/application.yml build/libs/myapp-0.1.war
```

Comment: I provide a link above (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) and it reads that you can also specify a yaml file without needing to take these extra steps. Did this not work for you? It does say you need SnakeYAML on the classpath for it to work.